# Did the US create and fund al-Qaeda?

Tags: united-states, terrorism

There are many claims that the US created and funded the terrorist group known as "Al-Qaeda". <sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA%E2%80%93al-Qaeda_controversy) [[2]](http://www.globalresearch.ca/more-evidence-u-s-funds-al-qaeda-terrorists-in-syria/5376522) [[3]](http://www.theinsider.org/news/article.asp?id=0228) and so on...</sup>

But how legitimate are those claims? Did the US **really** create al-Qaeda?

Comment: I think you should remove [2]. The others [1] and [3] are a claim that the CIA funded al-Qaeda during the Soviet war in Afghanistan, whereas [2] is about Syria (i.e. it's a different claim about more modern times).

Comment: You should reformulate this question so it asks for evidence, not opinions. We don't want to debated what "create" "fund", etc. mean. If there is a specific -- falsifiable -- theory, then we'll gladly examine it.

Comment: @Sklivvz How about, [It has been claimed that the CIA had ties with Osama Bin Laden's al-Qaeda and its "Afghan Arab" fighters when it armed Mujahideen groups against the Soviet Union during the Soviet war in Afghanistan.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA%E2%80%93al-Qaeda_controversy)?

Comment: This is all documented in the book "Taliban: Militant Islam, Oil and Fundamentalism in Central Asia" - it's no opinion piece, that book is well cited. I could answer this if it was open. The answer is YES - America trained and funded the people who would later form al-Qaeda, in an attempt to oust the Soviets from Afghanistan.

Comment: Answer is: YES: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Cyclone (CIA) program to arm and finance the Jihad warriors, mujahideen, in Afghanistan from 1979 to 1989,

Comment: Or better: did not CREATED it, but CIA helped to finance the people who wanted to create it.